# Translations in source code

Tags: translation

I have finished and deployed a WordPress site. Looking the source code inside browser tools, there are scripts embedded in the HTML code with all strings (original-translated) including all Gutenberg options, doesn't seem too secure.

This is an example:

```
(function( translations ){translations.locale_data.messages[""].domain = "default";wp.i18n.setLocaleData( translations.locale_data.messages, "default" );})({"translation-revision-date":"2018-12-26 13:33:36+0000","generator":"GlotPress\/2.4.0-alpha","domain":"messages","locale_data":{"messages":{"":{"domain":"messages","plural-forms":"nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;","lang":"es"},"Backtick":["Acento grave"],"Period":["Punto"],"Comma":["Coma"]}}});
```

Or this (inside a function):

```
"Given your current role, you can only link a video, you cannot upload.":["Con tu perfil actual solo puedes enlazar un v\u00eddeo, no puedes subirlo."]
```

Is it normal?

Comment: Why isn't it secure?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Is it normal? I've been checking different sites and not finding things like this

Comment: I'm not answering... You've stated in your question, that this doesn't seem too secure. Why do you think so?

Comment: It doesn't seem secure giving all information about a tool which edits some private/public information and is restricted for visitors.

Answer (score 1):

This is "normal" in WordPress 5 as this is what the new [wp_set_script_translations](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_script_translations/) function is for.

The function tells WordPress to associate a JSON file containing translations with a specific script that will make use of them. It makes use of them as you see, by embedding the translations as JavaScript objects.

You say this is not secure, but you don't say what you're concerned about. I would say it's as secure as any file you allow onto your server. You install PHP code from trusted sources and allow it to execute. Likewise with JavaScript. So apply the same caution to translations and don't install language packs from untrusted sources!